# Why is the average of a million random numbers not in the middle of the range?

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

So I was writing a script that used `random.randint()` in python, but it doesn't really matter since I think most mainstream languages have this "problem". It's like this: I set `i` to a random number and then add a random number 1 million times and then divide it by two. The outputs vary wildly, sometimes it's close to 0, sometimes close to 1, but by logic the output should pretty much be `0.5`. What is causing this change.

```py
from random import randint

i = randint(0, 1)
for x in range(1000000):
    i = (i + randint(0, 1)) / 2
print(i)
```

Comment: `randint(0, 1)` only returns either `0` or `1`, are you aware of that?

Comment: @Random Davis Yes, should not be affecting the output though, since it averages it.

Comment: I would try `sum([randint(0,1) for I in range(1000000)])/1000000`

Comment: The result would be ~0.5 if you were calculating the average of those numbers, but you aren't doing that. Furthermore, this approach is going to be very susceptible to trends. If you get a lot of numbers < 0.5 in a row, it will weigh the value of `i` to the point that the odd > 0.5 number won't affect it much, and vice versa for trends of numbers > 0.5. The result you are seeing is effectively telling you what the trend of the random numbers were at the end of the series.

Comment: @ArthurJulião always puts out 1 for me.

Comment: What you're calculating here isn't the average.  Only the final random number is fully effective, capable of changing the final result by +/- 0.5 all on its own.  The next-to-last number can affect the results by +/- 0.25, the one before that by +/- 0.125, and so on.  The first 0.999 million random numbers have no effect at all, the repeated divisions by two reduce their contributions to zero.

Comment: @gurkensaas my bad, actually the issue is `i = (i + randint(0, 1)) / 2`. That's not keeping track of the average, since if I add the numbers all to a list and divide its sum by its length, its value is wildly different than `i`. It's not clear why you think that's keeping track of the average or why you're doing that.

Comment: @jasonharper I see the problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your approach isn't calculating the average of all million numbers. It is merely repeatedly calculating an aggregate where each step is the average of the previous value and a new number. This is going to make it so every new value added to the series is going to have a disproportionately large effect on the resulting "average" value, contrary to a true average where each value affects the result equally.

To see what I mean, consider the following code:

```py
from random import randint

nums = [randint(0, 1) for x in range(0, 1000)]

avg = 0
for i in nums:
  avg += i
avg /= len(nums)

pseudo_avg = 0
for i in nums:
  pseudo_avg = (pseudo_avg + i) / 2

print('True Average: %s' % avg)
print('Pseudo-average: %s' % pseudo_avg)
```

On one run, I got the following as the result:

```
True Average: 0.492
Pseudo-average: 0.979068653199454
```

Answer (score 2):

Say you witness `0, 1, 0` in that order. The average is `(0 + 1 + 0)/3 = 1/3`. Your code (with, of course, `range(3)`) would give:

```
i = 0
i = (0 + 1)/2
i = (0 + 1/2)/2 = 1/4
```

So, firstly, you're not calculating averages.

Now, suppose you are at some in the iteration and `i` is some value between 0 and 1. You get a value of 0 next then `i = i/2`, effectively halving what ever you have. If you have a sequence of say 5 `0`s at the end, you will get a value `<= 1/2^5`) at the end. Now suppose instead the value is is 1 `i = (i+1)/2`. This converges quickly to `1`. Say `i` was, in the worst case `0`. Then if you read a string of `1`s, after only reading 2 `1`s you will end up at `0.75`.

(Note: You can show that `i` is always between `0` and `1` through induction.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about what you are trying, but take a look on this result :[image]

Maybe your way to calculate average is not suitable to your intent.